# Rails + Dragonfly gem: Saving image in a directory structure based on ActiveRecord object attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, paperclip, dragonfly-gem

I'm using [dragonfly gem](http://github.com/markevans/dragonfly) to manage images and attachments in my rails app and I need to store images in a specific directory structure based on my
user model.
let' say I have user model which has a name and each user has many
albums, which have a name also, then I want the images to be stored
in  `"#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/system/#{user.name}/#{user.album.name}/#{suffix}"`

I've managed to changed the root_path in dragon fly and I even
overrided relative_storage_path like this:

```
class MyDataStore < Dragonfly::DataStorage::FileDataStore
  private
   def relative_storage_path(suffix)
    "#{suffix}"
   end
end
```

but still, I don't know how I can pass the ActiveRecord object
attributes like `user.name` and `user.album.name` to `relative_storage_path`
to create my ideal path.

do you have any idea how I can do such a thing?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705003/rails-dragonfly-gem-saving-image-in-a-directory-structure-based-on-activerecor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mark Evans the gem author did me a favor and answered this question on google group. Here is his answer that worked pretty well for my case:

Hi there

You can't do this out of the box, because the data store is
purposefully designed to be very simple - you pass in data, it gives
you back a uid, etc.

If you want to do it you'll have to monkey-patch Attachment#save! like
so:

```
class Dragonfly::ActiveRecordExtensions::Attachment
  def save!
    destroy! if uid_changed?
    self.uid = app.datastore.store(temp_object, parent_model) if has_data_to_store?
  end
end
```

The only thing I've changed above is that datastore.store takes two
args now.

You'll then have to modify/monkey-patch
Dragonfly::DataStorage::FileDataStore#store to take into account the
second arg.

Out of interest, why do you want the images to be stored in that
format?

Cheers
Mark

Comment: Above answer is no longer needed as dragonfly supports custom storage paths now anyway: http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.Models.html#Storage_options

Comment: @MarkEvans that link is dead now :(

Comment: @MarkEvans I'm having the same problem but we don't have a model. We save the images as "Dragonfly[:images].store(data)". Is it possible to store those files in a different specific folder? I've put the full problem description here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288299/rails-dragonfly-find-files-in-use