# Rails Dragonfly find files in use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, dragonfly-gem

We are using Dragonfly for file and image upload in the app and in the Rails Admin.

**Dragonfly in app part**
Users can apply for jobs and add their resume as attachment. When user uploads attachments and sucesfully apply for a job the files get deleted.

**Dragonfly in Rails Admin part**
Admins can create pages with attachments and images in the Rails Admin part, these attachments are linked via the specific tables.

**Problem**
When a user is applying for a job but doesn't finish the apply the files remain unused on the server. Now dragonfly stores the files from the Admin on the same place as the user uploaded files.

**Question**
Is it possible to filter out the files that are not linked in the DB and bulk delete these files?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this simply by supplying a path when storing the data:

```
path = "ApplyAttachments/" + Time.now.strftime("%d%m%Y_%H%M") + "_" + rand(1000).to_s + "_" + data.original_filename.to_s
file["file"] = Dragonfly[:images].store(data, :path => path)
```